# How to insert a non-constant variable into a json url

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping

Sorry for the incomprehensible title, hopefully, I can clarify. The first section of code works fine, but now I want to insert all of the "uuid's" into the requests and acquire something from each one in a for loop, perhaps.

```
import requests
import json

uuids = []
count = 0
catacombs = []

data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&id=5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43").json()
for guild in data["guild"]["members"]:
    uuids.append(guild["uuid"])
```

Instead of having this...

```
data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&profile=0baac74f903143e49d24015d8bc3a733").json()
print(data)
```

I want to have the second parameter "profile" be taken from the previously acquired list like so.

```
data = requests.get("\"https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&profile=" + str(uuids[count]) + "\"").json()
print(data)
```

I get a whole slew of errors and I don't know where to even start on fixing this. I will clarify if need be. Thanks in advance, and again sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no extra `"` at the ends of such urls, so change

```
data = requests.get("\"https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&profile=" + str(uuids[count]) + "\"").json()
```

to

```
data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&profile=" + str(uuids[count])).json()
```